# Vimeo video lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, vimeo

I'm having trouble getting a [Swipebox.js](http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/) Vimeo video lightbox to work. I've also tried [Shadowbox](https://github.com/mjackson/shadowbox) without any luck.

The actual overlay works. The video just doesn't show. I've tried different video links, using a text link instead of an image, and tweaking the firing of the plugin.

Here's the actual page I'm trying to get to work (see video link at top):
[alookat.org/wavefront](http://alookat.org/wavefront).

Here's the `<a>` I'm targeting:

```
<a class="swipebox-video" href="http://vimeo.com/124510802">
    <img id="video-preview" src="img/video-preview.jpg" alt="Wavefront Introduction Video">
    <span></span>
</a>
```

The `<span>` is just for the play button. I've followed the instructions on the Swipebox page as closely as possible. All the Javascript & event firing should be in place.

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm not attached to Swipebox—I'll use anything that will get clicking on the image to show (and autoplay) the Vimeo video. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In Chrome, I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`. In Firefox, I get `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ':' after property name in object at line 1 column 4 of the JSON data`.

Comment: Interestingly, I [got your code to work](http://jsfiddle.net/kqc32skh/) using [Swipebox from cdnjs.com](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.swipebox). But it [doesn't seem to work](http://jsfiddle.net/kqc32skh/1/) with Swipebox from [BrutalDesign's github](https://github.com/brutaldesign/swipebox/tree/master/src/js). The files also [seem to be different](https://www.diffchecker.com/ilydhuzi), but have the same version number. I'm not sure what any of this indicates.

Comment: @showdev I noticed that error too. Just not sure what the fix is.  Thanks for that. That's really useful. I've just tried to use that version, but with no luck. I'm getting the following error in the console: 
`[Error] Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (124510802, line 0)        file://player.vimeo.com/video/124510802?byline=0&portrait=0&color=cccccc&autoplay=false`

Comment: Strange. In your code, are you linking to the video using the `file://` scheme? Does my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqc32skh/) work in your browser?

Comment: @showdev no, the console has added `file://` before the URL. Yes, the fiddle does work! Just not when I replicate your code to mine. Maybe it's an issue with the external resources linking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: the plugin works when hosted live, but not locally. More specifically, the Vimeo video only loads when the page is loaded on a server. Thanks @showdev for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/101Helper/docs/1a5967de5f298b3434c498858adf8a98146f9aaf/player.css" />
<div id="jquery-script-menu">
<a rel="nofollow" href="Javascript:" class="link-lightbox" data-videoid="YOUR VIDEO ID" data-videosite="vimeo"><img src="VIDEO IMAGE URL"/> OR YOUR CAN ADD SOME TEXT HERE WHICH WILL ACT AS TRIGGER TO OPEN LIGHT BOX</a><br />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/101Helper/docs/master/player.js"></script></div>
```

Replace **YOUR VIDEO ID** with your video's ID which you want to play in the pop up light box.

Also

Replace **`<img src="VIDEO IMAGE URL"/>` OR YOUR CAN ADD SOME TEXT HERE WHICH WILL ACT AS TRIGGER TO OPEN LIGHT BOX** with your image URL or some text to set a trigger which when clicked will open the pop up light box.

*Source: http://www.the101helper.com/2016/10/jquery-on-click-pop-up-light-box-video.html*